# Jquery on click ajax success hide one element and show another

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get this code to work properly; I want it so, that after the ajax is done, the button is hidden and the static text in the `.min` element is shown. There are about six or seven `.button` elements and when I click on the `.mine`, it shows the `.min` for all of the `.button` elements.

```
function mine_board()
{
    $('#star_count .button').on('click', '.mine', function() 
    {
        sid = this.id;
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        x = $(this);
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:"purchase.php?mode=planet", 
            type:"POST", 
            data:{sid:sid}, 
            success: function()
            { 
                x.fadeOut();
                $('.min').fadeOut().removeClass('hidden').fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Use the x element you marked and find or closest to get to you specific .min element

Answer (score 0):

As Lior Asta wrote, instead of `$('.min')`, use `x.siblings('.min')`, assuming they are siblings, or `x.find('.min')` if it's a child of the button?